# removing duplicates depending on combination of columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
id  date    latest  seq
1   2020    Y       2
1   2019    N       1
2   2020    Y       3
3   2020    Y       4
4   2020    Y       5
4   2020    N       5
5   2020    Y       6
5   2020    N       6
```

here the IDs 1,2,3 have diff seq num and considered different records. But IDs 4 and 5 have the same seq number and considered as duplicates as per my requirement. So I have to remove the ones with 'latest' 'N' and my output table should look like as following one.

```
id  date    latest  seq
1   2020    Y       2
1   2019    N       1
2   2020    Y       3
3   2020    Y       4
4   2020    Y       5
5   2020    Y       6
```

How to make it happen in an SQL statement. Please help.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to *delete* these "duplicate" records, then try:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    latest = 'N' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.seq = t1.seq AND
                  t2.latest = 'Y');
```

If you instead just want to view/select your expected output, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    latest = 'Y' OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.seq = t1.seq AND
                      t2.latest = 'Y');
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

Here is a demo for the second select query:

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

From many ways I would choose `not exists` to achieve it,

```
select t1.*
  from table1 t1
 where not exists (select 1
                     from table1 t2
                    where t1.id = t2.id
                      and t1.seq = t2.seq
                      and t1.latest = 'N'
                      and t2.latest = 'Y'
 )
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use aggregation:

```
select id, date, max(latest) as latest, seq
from t
group by id, date, seq;
```